# Sending a variable from a function in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a JS script with a map, which works well:

```js
var lat = 0;
var lng = 0;

function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
  lat = e.latlng.lat;
  lng = e.latlng.lng;
  console.log(e.latlng);

  L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup("Tutaj jesteś!!!").openPopup();
  L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

function onLocationError(e) {
  //alert(e.message);
}

var map = L.map('mapdiv', {
  editable: true,
  fadeAnimation: false
}).setView([54.35070881441067, 18.641191756395074], 15);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  maxZoom: 30,
  zoomControl: true,
  detectRetina: true
}).addTo(map);

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
map.locate({
  setView: true,
  maxZoom: 16
});

let myFilter = ['grayscale:100%'];
let myTileLayer = L.tileLayer.colorFilter('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '<a href="https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Maps_Terms_of_Use">Wikimedia</a>',
  filter: myFilter,
}).addTo(map);

/*
  lc = L.control.locate({
    strings: {
      title: "Show me where I am, yo!"
    }
  }).addTo(map);
*/

var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    shadowSize: [50, 64],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
  }
});

var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({
  iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png'
}),
redIcon = new LeafIcon({
  iconUrl: 'leaf-red.png'
}),
orangeIcon = new LeafIcon({
  iconUrl: 'leaf-orange.png'
});

L.icon = function(options) {
  return new L.Icon(options);
};

L.marker([54.45070881441067, 18.541191756395074], {
  icon: greenIcon
}).addTo(map).bindPopup('yyyyyy.<br> Easily customizable.');
L.marker([54.35070881441367, 18.641191756395774], {
  icon: redIcon
}).addTo(map).bindPopup('xxxxxxx.<br> Easily customizable.').openPopup();

L.marker([54.58273849989086, 18.373226338357547], {
  icon: greenIcon
}).addTo(map).bindPopup('yyyyyy.<br> Easily customizable.');

L.EditControl = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    position: 'topleft',
    callback: null,
    kind: '',
    html: ''
  },
  onAdd: function(map) {
    var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control leaflet-bar'),
      link = L.DomUtil.create('a', '', container);

    link.href = '#';
    link.title = 'Create a new ' + this.options.kind;
    link.innerHTML = this.options.html;
    L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop).on(link, 'click', function() {
      window.LAYER = this.options.callback.call(map.editTools);
    }, this);
    return container;
  }
});

var circle = L.circle([lat, lng], {
  radius: 1000
}).addTo(map);

circle.enableEdit();
circle.on('dblclick', L.DomEvent.stop).on('dblclick', circle.toggleEdit);
//circle.on('editable:vertex:drag', function (e) {

map.on('editable:drawing:move', function(e) {
  console.log(circle.getLatLng())
  console.log(circle.getRadius());
});
```

In the `onLocationFound()` function I set values for the `lat` and `lng` variables. I would like to use those variables in this code:

```
var circle = L.circle([lat, lng], {
  radius: 1000
}).addTo(map);
```

However it's not working. I haven't got an error in the console. How can I fix this?

Comment: The `onLocationFound` callback function might not be running at all. I see that the contents of your `onLocationError` callback function are commented out. If you uncomment that (or add a `console.error()`) there, you might get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `onLocationFound()` function is only called when the `locationfound` event fires on the map, yet you attempt to use the `lat` and `lng` values before this happens and hence the values are `undefined`.

To fix the problem move the `var circle = ...` line *inside* the `onLocationFound()` function:

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
  lat = e.latlng.lat;
  lng = e.latlng.lng;
  console.log(e.latlng);

  L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup("Tutaj jesteś!!!").openPopup();
  L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);

  var circle = L.circle([lat, lng], {
    radius: 1000
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

You can see from this example that your code is already doing similar in this line:

```
L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
```

The difference in the code you're trying to get working is simply the radius you define for the circle.

Also note that you can then also remove the global definition for those variables, as globals should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Thank you. I add your code here: https://newapp.ovh/test/map.html and I have error:  Geolocation error: position unavailable.

Comment: That page works fine for me. It sounds like you haven't enabled geolocation access from the browser permissions.